# How to check if a string contains all words from a multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to coding but I'm trying to accomplish the following.

I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
var requiredProducts = [{
    product: 'PRODUCT 1',
    keywords: ['KEYWORD1', 'KEYWORD2', 'KEYWORD3'],
    price: '50.00'
},{
    product: 'PRODUCT 2',
    keywords: ['KEYWORD4', 'KEYWORD5', 'KEYWORD6'],
    price: '50.00'
}];
```

I'm retrieving a string from a HTML element, say for example:

> This string is fantastic, it contains KEYWORD1 and KEYWORD3, and KEYWORD2

How can I check if the string contains all of the keywords from any the keyword arrays(the order of the keywords shouldn't matter). I've been trying various things for days and haven't really achieved anything but a sore brain.

Help gratefully appreciated.

If it helps this is the code block I'm trying to add it to. The new function should be called from the '***' and allow this function to continue if the keywords are all found.

```
function checkPopup(jNode) {
console.log(scriptName + 'Found new popup.');
console.log(scriptName + 'Checking popup...');
linkText = jNode.attr("title");
linkText = linkText.toUpperCase();
console.log(scriptName + 'Popup: ' + linkText);
if *** {
    console.log(scriptName + 'Popup matched.');
} else {
    console.log(scriptName + 'Product not matched.');
}
}
```

Comment: 1) please post what you've tried. It's important for us to see the context you're working in 2) What bearing does the `product` have on the keywords to be searched for?

Comment: Ditto what @RoryMcCrossan said. Please post **code examples** of what you describe as  *"trying various things for days"*.

Comment: Hi Rory, thank you for the reply. I haven't kept track of the various methods I've tried (I'm fresh out of the box). Basically I've scoured the net and tried the various solutions I came across. The issue I believe was adjusting them to my requirement (In most cases the fact I'm using a multidimensional array). The product I return elsewhere in my code, mostly when a price matches, I have this part working okay.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.every` It will run a predicate function over the items in an array and only return true if each iteration returns true.

Please note that `Array.prototype.every` is only supported in modern browsers.

```js
var requiredProducts = [{
  product: 'PRODUCT 1',
  keyword: ['KEYWORD1', 'KEYWORD2', 'KEYWORD3'],
  price: '50.00'
}, {
  product: 'PRODUCT 2',
  keyword: ['KEYWORD4', 'KEYWORD5', 'KEYWORD6'],
  price: '50.00'
}];

var str1 = 'This string is fantastic, it contains KEYWORD1 and KEYWORD3, and KEYWORD2'
var str2 = 'This string is fantastic, it contains KEYWORD4 and KEYWORD5, and KEYWORD6'


function matchProductByKeywords(str, products) {
  return products.filter(function(product){
    return product.keyword.every(
      function(word) {
        return str.match(word)
      }
    )
  })
}
console.log(
  'str1', matchProductByKeywords(str1, requiredProducts),
  'str2', matchProductByKeywords(str2, requiredProducts)
)
```

here is a shim for every that you can use. for unsupported browsers

```
Array.prototype.every = Array.prototype.every || function(predicate){
  for (var ii = 0, ll = this.length; ii < ll; ii+=1) {
    if (!predicate.call(this, this[ii], ii, this)) {
     return false
    }
  }
  return true
}
```

Comment: should always clarify when using features that don't have full browser support

Comment: This also doesn't solve the issue. Yes it check each value individually, but you do not check them all together

Comment: it checks that `every` keyword in the required array is in the string. That was the question.

Comment: This works for the keywords attached to `PRODUCT 1`, but not `PRODUCT 2`? I currently have 36 products to check keywords against.

Comment: @MarkSwift You need to be clearer in your question. The keyword array's are the same, they will both match. What are you expecting to be the returned value?. Do you want to know which products match, or just that one of the products matches.

Comment: The script will only be run on the most recent versions of Chrome, so I presume the shim isn't required?

Comment: @synthet1c Apologies, I'm new and didn't consider it wasn't clear enough. For now, I only want the function to return `true` if ALL `keyword`'s for a `product` are matched. Later I'd like to return the product name and price (but that's not required now).

Comment: @MarkSwift the code is updated to only return true if all keywords from all products are in the string. It is achieved by running an every over the requiredProducts array and an every over each keywoard. The shim will not be required for chrome. I just added it as someone complained that the function was not supported in all browsers.

Comment: @synthet1cI just tried it... I think I need to go back to school and learn how to explain myself as perhaps I'm still not being clear enough? I want it to return true, if ALL keywords match to a particular product.

Example:

String 1 `This string is fantastic, it contains KEYWORD1 and KEYWORD3, and KEYWORD2`

String 2 `This string is fantastic, it contains KEYWORD4 and KEYWORD6, and KEYWORD5`

String 1 would match to `PRODUCT 1`, String 2 would match `PRODUCT 2`.

Comment: @MarkSwift I just changed it to return the products that match the keywords. if you just want a boolean you can change `filter` to `some`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are not using external modules or libraries to calculate the intersection of two arrays. Try this:

```
var phrase = "This string is fantastic, it contains KEYWORD1 and KEYWORD3, and KEYWORD2";
var words = phrase.split(/[\s,]/);

var results = []

requiredProducts.forEach(function (item) {
    var intersection = item.keyword.filter(function(value) {
        return words.indexOf(value) > -1;
    });
    results.push({
        product: item.product,
        match: item.keyword.length === intersection.length,
        intersection: intersection
    });
});

console.log(results);
```